# Pixel rounding on Android vs Iphone vs Safari/Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, android, css, rendering

I'm working on a mobile site for a client and I'm having issues with my slideshow method, which is as follows:

- A wrapping container of 100% width, overflow:hidden, position:relative
- A ul inside of this container with a width of (#children*100)%, position:relative
- Variable number of lis with a width of (100/#li)%, floated left, each containing an image with width:100%
- For every iteration, the ul's 'left' property is    decremented 100%

This method works great on desktop browsers and mobile safari, but the android browsers treat float percentages poorly, rendering them incorrectly. I have no way of knowing for sure but it seems as though when I apply a width of 100/6 = 16.66666667% to an li it's being rendered as 16%, even though when I query that element's width via javascript it returns the normal truncated 16.6667% width. The result is that with each iteration through the slideshow, the images become more and more un-centered toward the left, due to them not occupying the correct amount of space in the wrapping container.

Interestingly, when I decrease the number of elements to a number that evenly divides 100, say 100/5 = 20%, this issue completely goes away.

I've looked through previous threads concerning pixel rounding, but I don't think that's the problem. From what I gather, pixel rounding occurs when the calculation of pixels has a remainder and the browser has to round the result to the nearest pixel, this seems to be an issue of the browser not understanding what a fractional percentage is.

Has anyone else run into an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

A number of browsers do not handle fractions of a percentage properly:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?547308-CSS-percentage-width-roundoff